# Login failed for user . SSIS Package solution

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

1. Developed an SSIS package and linked with the C# application.
2. Created a Windows user for SQL server management and used in the connection string as shown in the image.

[image: C# CODE]

3. If running from visual studio, it is working fine. But the same package hosted on the IIS server. While running from the server, getting a login failed error.

Should I refer anything else in the connection string?

[image: Error]

Comment: That connection string doesn't look like it's using Integrated security, as you're declaring the username and password as part of the connection string. As a result it appears your trying to connect as the SQL Login `[domain]\dwh_service` (rather than the Domain User); and hence the error (as that login does not exist).

Comment: The AD authentication uses always the credentials of the running process, which I assume you noticed when you blurred the userid from the error message.